# Using an Android phone touchscreen as a PC mouse, including gestures

Tags: java, android, input, mouse, gesture

I'm looking to develop a system to allow the use of an Android phone's touchscreen to control the mouse on a PC, but am not entirely sure how easy this would be, or how I would go about it. I imagine in order to send data from the touchscreen to the PC I would need to use Bluetooth or Wi-Fi, but then how would I go about reading this on the PC?

Secondly, I realise I would be able to detect gestures on the phone (e.g. pinch-zoom), but how would I go about using this information at the PC end? I.e. Once the computer receives information that the user wants to zoom in, is there a simple way to then increase the zoom in the current application (e.g. Zoom-in within Google Chrome)?

Thanks for your help, I will add more information if it's unclear what my question is.

Comment: Sounds like this isn't really so much of an android question as it is a "What can I do with bluetooth events I recieve on a PC" question. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, that's essentially what I'm asking. And what's the simplest way to receive Bluetooth/Wi-Fi events on a PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should split your system in three parts:

1. Android activity with touch events registrating
2. Android service to pass the commands to the pc via bluetooth or usb
3. System application for the desktop to interpret the commands and emulate the mouse. For Windows systems window messages will be enough.

Comment: is there a way to make the app work even if the screen is off

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth will probably be your best bet. If you use wi-fi you're going to have to set up some sort of client-server protocol which could get complicated. For doing bluetooth communication, you might want to checkout the [LightBlue](http://lightblue.sourceforge.net/) python library for bluetooth communication. I've never used it, but hey it's python. So it should be super easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using Bluetooth. You will have a server on pc side listening for clients, Android phone in this case. Once communication is setup you can then send x,y coords or other commands from your phone to your pc.

You can start looking into win32 api calls like `WSALookupServiceBegin`, `WSALookupServiceNext`. It is similar to sockets programming.